# Windows 10 update and reboots happening for last 24 hours

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I have a 3.5 years old HP Pavillion desktop(Intel Quad Core Processor, 32 GB RAM, 2 GB Nvidia Graphics card and regular hard drives - 7200 RPM).
I have microsoft family safety enabled and this computer is mainly used by my son. He had 4 hours yesterday and prior to that my wife was using this computer. 
Windows 10 update started happening almost at 2:45 pm central and it's going on and on. System keeps on rebooting and that's it.
Twice i have power off this computer but the same phenomena is going on. Once i went to the recovery mode and got the hard drive checked - no errors were found...in that session i tried to return back to the operating system and exit.
Now once again it's series of reboots and restarts and updates are going on?

Also referred to this [thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/windows-10-update-takes-so-long-tome/6b170692-67ff-44da-b8eb-e1fe7846277f?rtAction=1526738172872)

What exactly is going on? And how i can get the control of this computer back to me?

Comment: What do you want exactly? Do you want to turn off windows update?

Comment: Yes. This update is still going on...it's more than 28 hours now. I want to regain control of my computer.

Answer (score 1):

Tried almost everything:
1) Recover using the recover partition - no success(very interesting - what is recovery partition then)
2) Recovery media was of no use.
3) Reset to the last good configuration(system restore point - unfortunately it seems that this update removed all of them).
It seems that this update made the computer almost not usable at all.

Finally i have to try install from fresh using Windows 10 media. This time i installed on the separate hard drive so that i can recover the data from the previous hard drive(which contains windows and some other programs),

Windows 10 very unreliable and unpredictable it seems.

Comment: Windows Update was always dangerous. Precautions are counseled before, such as taking an image backup of the system disk (and not with Windows Backup).

Answer (score 0):

You could recover the system via the boot recovery options to a system restore point that precedes that problem.

Then set Windows Update to postpone updates as much as possible, and maybe Microsoft will fix the problem later.

Comment: that didn't worked either.